# Spring Boot Elastic Search

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

i) We are planning to build a new application using Spring Boot 2 and use Elastic Search for our application searches.

ii) Spring Boot 2.X comes with ElasticSearch 5.5 (ElasticSearch 5.5 doesn't support High-Level-Rest-Client)
First version of High Level Rest Client was released with Elastic Search 5.6

**Question:**

1) Given the above what are the Elastic Client options for our Spring Boot 2.X application to connect with ElasticSearch?

2) Any one here would know more about the spring boot roadmap as to when will it release an upgrade that can support Elastic Search High-Level-Rest-Client?

Answer (score 0):

With spring boot you're (nearly) free to choose the ES version you want. But probably you're asking about spring-data-elasticsearch? If so, then:

1.1) Use the high level rest client standalone without spring-data-elasticsearch, then you can start with a recent version of ES. This is my favorite approach as I often need functions not supported by spring-data-elasticsearch.

1.2) Use spring-data-elasticsearch in the current version and update later (this will keep you on a older es version, as the transportClient needs the versions in some way synchronized) or use a snapshot of spring-data-elasticsearch (your app will be probably still under development when a stable release will be available)

1.3) Drop spring-data-elasticsearch and use https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest which seems to be the underlying solution in the moore release (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/147)

1.4) Use your very own implementation (probably not a really good option) ;)

2) With spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2 M1 (Release Train Moore) this issue should be resolved. Please see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-220 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-407 for more details.